# A sum of polyharmonic series

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, reference-request, estimation

Could anyone suggest how to obtain good estimates from above $\vee$ below  for the following finite series:
$$F(N,k):=\sum_{n_1 + \dots + n_k < N, \; n_i\ge 1}\frac{1}{n_1(n_1+n_2)\dots(n_1 + \dots + n_k)}?$$
For $k=1$ this is just a harmonic series. One may sort of approximate it by an integral 
$$
\int_{1}^{N-k}x_1^{-1}\int_{x_1+1}^{N-k+1}x_2^{-1}\dots \int_{x_{k-1}+1}^{N-1}x_k\, dx_k\dots dx_1,
$$
but this yields neither an upper nor a lower bound that easily.

Alternatively, I am looking for estimates for expanded expressions $\Phi(N,k) = \sum_{j=0}^{k-1}F(N,j)$ with $F(N,0)=1$, or even $\Theta(N,k) = \sum_{i=0}^{L}\frac{\Phi(ik,k)}{ik}$, as some neat cancellations perhaps happen there.

Comment: So alternatively, you are summing over all increasing sequences in $\{1,\ldots,N-1\}$ of length $k$?

Comment: Sorry. Right, that's what I do.

Comment: If $N\leq k$ then $F(N,k)=0$. Splitting $F(N,k)$ into sums with $n_k=j$ constant yields
$$F(N,k)=\sum_{j=k}^{N-1}F(j,k-1).$$
Repeating this twice more yields
\begin{eqnarray*}
F(N,k)
&=&\sum_{j=k}^{N-1}\sum_{i=k-1}^{j-1}F(i,k-2)=\sum_{i=k-1}^{N-2}(N-1-i)F(i,k-2)\\
&=&\sum_{i=k-1}^{N-2}(N-1-i)\sum_{l=k-2}^{i-1}F(l,k-3)=\sum_{l=k-2}^{N-3}C(N,l)F(l,k-3),
\end{eqnarray*}
where the coefficients $C(N,l)$ are given by
\begin{eqnarray*}
C(N,l)&=&\sum_{i=l+1}^{N-2}(N-1-i)\\&=&(N-l-2)(N-1)-\frac{(N-2)(N-1)-l(l+1)}{2}\\&=&\tfrac12(N-l-\tfrac54)(N+l+\tfrac74).
\end{eqnarray*}
(Continued...)

Comment: (...Continued) Perhaps someone more familiar with such recursions sees a nicer closed form for the coefficients as we repeat this substitution, up to $k$ times? At least it seems that $F(N,k)$ is polynomial of degree $k$ in $N$?

Answer (score 3):

Not a complete answer, some relatively simple bounds on $F(N,k)$. The sum $F(N,k)$ runs over all increasing sequences of length $k$ in $\{1,\ldots,N-1\}$. There are precisely $\binom{N-1}{k}$ such sequences, and clearly each summand is at most $\tfrac{1}{k!}$, which shows that
$$F(N,k)\leq\frac{1}{k!}\binom{N-1}{k}.$$
Similarly, a lower bound $F(N,k)$ comes from the fact that every summand is bounded below by
$$\frac{1}{N(N-1)(N-2)\cdots(N-k+1)}=\frac{(N-k)!}{N!},$$
which shows that 
$$F(N,k)\geq\frac{(N-k)!}{N!}\binom{N-1}{k}=\frac{N-k}{N(k!)}=\frac{1}{k!}-\frac{1}{(k-1)!N}$$

---

Alternatively, here's a proof by induction on $k$ that $F(N,k)\leq(N-k)^k$ for all $N,k\geq1$: For $k=1$ and all $N\geq1$ we have
$$F(N,1)=H_{N-1}\leq(N-1)^1= P(N,1).$$
If $F(j,k-1)\leq P(j,k-1)$ for all $j\in\Bbb{N}$ then
$$F(N,k)=\sum_{j=k}^{N-1}F(j,k-1)\leq\sum_{j=k}^{N-1}P(j,k-1)
=\sum_{j=k}^{N-1}(j-(k-1))^{k-1}\leq(N-k)(N-k)^{k-1}=P(N,k).$$

Answer (score 0):

Occasionally, by revisiting the answers to [my earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3164285/regular-sum-of-hypercube-regions-volumes), in which the same problem was addressed yet a computational error was made in problem posing, I found out that one can write $F(N,k)$ as
$$
\frac{1}{(N-1)!}\sum_{1\le m_1 < \dots < m_{N-1-k} < N} m_1m_2\dots m_{N-k-1}
$$
The sum here is the [unsigned Stirling number of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind#Expansions_for_fixed_k), so that all the established recurrences and estimates may apply.

I am obliged to [G Cab](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/317234/g-cab) and [Servaes](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/30382/servaes) for helping me out with this problem.